# How to get a ridge from a fingerprint's minutiae

Tags: java, fingerprint

I binarized the fingerprint, thinned it with YYZhang's algorithm, got the minutiaes looking around of a pixel with this method

```
public static ArrayList<Point> timesPattern01(int i, int j, byte[][] image){

        ArrayList<Point> ps = new ArrayList<>();    


        if(image[i-1][j]==0 && image[i-1][j+1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i-1,j+1)); 
        if(image[i-1][j+1]==0 && image[i][j+1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i,j+1));
        if(image[i][j+1]==0 && image[i+1][j+1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i+1,j+1));
        if(image[i+1][j+1]==0 && image[i+1][j]==1) ps.add(new Point(i+1,j));
        if(image[i+1][j]==0 && image[i+1][j-1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i+1,j-1));
        if(image[i+1][j-1]==0 && image[i][j-1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i,j-1));
        if(image[i][j-1]==0 && image[i-1][j-1]==1) ps.add(new Point(i-1,j-1));
        if(image[i-1][j-1]==0 && image[i-1][j]==1) ps.add(new Point(i-1,j));

        return ps;
    }
```

And

```
for(int i=Wx+Xfactor; i<Ex-Xfactor; i++){
        for(int j=Ny+Yfactor; j<Sy-Yfactor; j++){
            ArrayList<Point> patterns = timesPattern01(i,j,fpImage);
            if(fpImage[i][j]==1){
                if(patterns.size() ==1){
                    termination.add(new Minutiae("termination",patterns,new Point(i,j)));

                }
                if(patterns.size()==3){
                    bifurcation.add(new Minutiae("bifurcation",patterns,new Point(i,j)));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where (Wx or Ex)+Xfactor and (Sy or Ny)+ Yfactor are the border of the fingerprint, so I wont get borderly false minutiaes

But My problem is, to get minutiae's orientation or even remove false minutiaes I need to track the ridge. How can I track the ridge, or even worse how can I track 3 ridge from a bifurcation point? Sorry but i can't think in a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

NIST provides detailed descriptions of their algorithms for templating in their [User Guide to NIST Biometric Image Software.](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=51097) The software is also in the public domain if you want to take a look at the source code.

Pages 62 - 68 of the document detail methods for elimination of erroneous minutia.